# What is the best way to configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer / resource folders?

Tags: java, spring

I have a (gradle/java/eclipse) project with what seems to me to be quite a standard folder structure

```
...main
  java
  ...controller
  ...service
  resources
  webapp
  ...resources
  WEB-INF
```

I'm having an issue I just don't understand although I have worked around it in a very messy way.  If I specify the controllers folder in the component scan of my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter then the services classes can't pick up properties using the configured PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean.  If I broaden the component scan out the jsp files don't pick up the css includes!

So with this config class all is well but the properties aren't resolved int he service implementation class

config class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "comm.app.controller" })
@PropertySource({ "classpath:app.properties" }) 
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

//used to handle html put and delete rest calls
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

}

Service implementation class begins

```
@Service("appService")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:app.properties" })
public class appServiceImpl implements appService {

private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

@Value("${property.reference}")
private String propref; 

   ...
```

In this case ${property.reference} is not picked up but the view page styling (picked up from ...webapp\resources... .css) is fine.

If I change

```
  @ComponentScan({ "comm.app.controller" })
```

to

```
  @ComponentScan({ "comm.app" })
```

The properties are picked up (presumably because the propertyConfig bean comes into scope ?) but the local styling files can't be found ?  Any link references to files webapp\resources... .css fails.

In the end I came to a bad (!?) solution of

1) keeping the scope of @ComponentScan({ "comm.app.controller" })

2) hacking the serviceimplementation class as so...

```
@Configuration
@Service("appService")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:app.properties" })
public class appServiceImpl implements appService {

private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Value("${property.reference}")
private String propref; 

   ...
```

Can anyone tell me if I've configured the path the the resources file incorrectly or maybe should be doing something differently with the propertyConfig bean ?  (maybe injecting it or declaring another one in a different configuration file ?)